# R How do i split a string into a vector so that each place in the vector corresponds to a letter

Tags: r

I am trying to split a string let's say "abcde" into a vector of "a","b","c","d","e"

How can i do that?

i have tried strsplit but that makes it into 1 element

```
a=unlist(strsplit("abcde", split=" "))
```

Comment: You need to split on an empty string: `unlist(strsplit("abcde", split=""))`; from `?strsplit`: *If empty matches occur, in particular if ‘split’ has length 0, ‘x’ is split into single characters*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need the `split = ""`

```
unlist(strsplit('abcde', ''))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you this worked feel a bit stupid, but hey i am still learning. (cant tag it as answered yet)